# Can't find file AFJSONRequestOperation.h with AFNetworking and AFOAuth2Client

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am using cocoapods to install AFNetworking and AFOAuth2Client. The issue is that it can't import a header file, AFJSONREquestOperation. I have no idea where this dependency lies. Is it another pod or extension to AFNetworking?

Comment: What do you mean you "can't import" the header files? What error is it showing?

Comment: It just can't find the file in the project. I would assume it would have been in AFNetworking but I guess not.

Answer (score 3):

It depends of you installed AFNetworking 2.x version, but AFOAuth2 used 1.x version (the latest 1.x is 1.3.3)

If you used Cocoapods, just write in pod file
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.3.3'  and than run "pod install"

Answer (score 3):

@LIAL's answer is correct -- as of right now, AFOAuth2Client is not compatible with AFNetworking 2.0. There is an open pull request https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client/pull/55 that is supposed to make AFOAuth2Client work with AFNetworking 2.0.

You could fork the repo of mlwelles or use https://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client.git by modifying your Podfile for AFOAuth2Client line to look like this:

```
pod 'AFOAuth2Client', :git => 'git://github.com/mlwelles/AFOAuth2Client.git'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try importing it like this:

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFJSONRequestOperation.h>
```

If you can't that way, please make sure you are using Xcode 5. Happened to me when using Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: That doesn't work either. AFJSONRequestOperation is not in my project, for whatever reason. And I am using the latest xcode too. 5.0.1 I think.

Comment: Not even importing the whole ```#import <AFNetworking.h>``` ?

Comment: Carlos, basic premise is that the file is not even in the codebase. A string search does not find it.

Comment: I don't know what's happening there, sorry. But that happened to me once on Xcode 4.6.3, but on Xcode 5 BetaX that stopped from happening and I never cared about it anymore, didn't even try/need to understand. My lineup is ```ruby 2.0.0p195```, ```cocoapods 0.27.1```, ```AFNetworking ~> 1.3.3```

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I might try version 1.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

**AFHTTPRequestOperationManager Based Code**

AFNetworking 2.x

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

AFNetworking 3.x

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

**AFHTTPRequestOperation Based Code**

AFNetworking 2.x

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/resources/123.json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

AFNetworking 3.x

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/resources/123.json"];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:URL.absoluteString parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This answer it's helpful for both user who have use AFNetworking 2.x & 3.x
Thanks.